# Calculus: find total cost of first 500 widgets and next 500 widgets with fixed overhead cost

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to solve this with fixed startup cost component

If the marginal cost of producing x widgets is   $C'(x)=25-0.5x+0.002x^2$
(measured in cents per widget) and the fixed start-up cost for the business is 
$C(0)=\$30,000$

1. find the total cost of producing the first $500$ widgets,
2. find the cost of producing the next $500$ widgets.

I'm not sure how to solve this with fixed startup cost component

If the marginal cost of producing x widgets is   $C'(x)=25-0.5x+0.002x^2$
(measured in cents per widget) and the fixed start-up cost for the business is 
$C(0)=\$30,000$

1. find the total cost of producing the first $500$ widgets,
2. find the cost of producing the next $500$ widgets.

I have found the cost function as C= 25x - 0.25x^2 +0.00067...x^3 + A

C(500) = 25(500)-0.25(500)+0.002/2(500)^3+$30,000= 31,373.75

C(1000) = 25(1000)-0.25(1000)+0.002/2(1000)^3+$30,000= $40,247.50

C(1000) - C(500) = $40,247.5 - 31,373.75 = 8873.75

Cost of first 500 = $31.373.75

Cost of next 500 = $8873.75

I'm not sure if I have this right.

Comment: My level of knowledge on calculus is very basic

Comment: The cost is given by the function $C(x)$, but you're given the derivative $C^\prime (x)$. Do you know how to recover a function from its derivative?

Comment: by Integration?

Comment: exactly. Try to do that, and update the question with any progress you have. If you figure out the answer, you should post it here too, as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the cost function as C= 25x - 0.25x^2 +.002/2(x)^3 + A

C(500) = 25(500)-0.25(500)+0.002/2(500)^3+$30,000= 31,373.75

C(1000) = 25(1000)-0.25(1000)+0.002/2(1000)^3+30,000=40,247.50

C(1000) - C(500) = $40,247.5 - 31,373.75 = 8873.75

Cost of first 500 = $31,373.75

Cost of next 500 = $8873.75

Comment: To write mathematics like the other answerers, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a)$ $C(500) = C(0)+\displaystyle \int_{0}^{500} (0.002x^2-0.5x+25)dx= 30,000+...$

$b)$ $C(1000) - C(500) = \displaystyle \int_{500}^{1000} (0.002x^2-0.5x+25)dx=...$

Answer (score 0):

You found the cost function correctly, though use other letter for constant of integration to avoid confusion:
$$C(x)=25x-0.25x^2+\frac{0.002}{3}x^3+A.$$
Then use the initial condition to find $A$:
$$C(0)=A=30,000.$$
Hence, $C(x)=25x-0.25x^2+\frac{0.002}{3}x^3+30,000$ is the total cost function. Now you must calculate a) $C(500)$; b) $C(1000)-C(500)$.